# How to fix ext4_free_inode corrupt filesystem?

Tags: ext4, corruption

I got a RPi4 with an external hard drive, it had a kernel panic

```
---[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init!
```

I pulled the plug on it and on restart I'm getting a bunch of filesystem errors:

```
EXT4-fs error (device sda1) in ext4_free_inode:363: Corrupt filesystem
```

I tried to force an fsck on reboot by:

- `sudo touch /forcefsck`
- add `fsck.mode=force` to `/boot/cmdline.txt`
- `reboot --reboot`

But the check completed and the error appeared again.

Comment: Is SMART happy with the disk?

Comment: I didn't have `smartctl` in my path, chose not to install new things while trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

After forcing a `fsck` on boot, I found in `/var/log/syslog` this message:

> EXT4-fs (sda1): warning: mounting fs with errors, running e2fsck is recommended

So I unmounted the drive and executed:

```
e2fsck -y /dev/sda1
reboot --reboot
```

That was enough to fix it.

Comment: Good to hear you cracked it, but doesn't your question say that you'd already executed a filesystem check and it _didn't_ fix it? Curious.

Comment: The initial filesystem check forced a `fsck` run and later I did an `e2fsck`, those two do different things I assume.

Comment: Same thing. `fsck` is the generic interface and it will call `e2fsck` for an `extN` filesystem